# Grouping list of names into N lists by values

Tags: python, dictionary

If you get a list of names with specific keys to group by (DAY-VARIABLE-DIRECTION), for example:

```
fileList: ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif', '26.LST.asc.16.tif', '26.LST.des.1.tif', '26.LST.des.10.tif', '26.LST.des.13.tif', '26.LST.des.4.tif', '26.LST.des.7.tif', '26.NDVI.des.12.tif', '26.NDVI.des.15.tif', '26.NDVI.des.3.tif', '26.NDVI.des.6.tif', '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']
```

You can use the N keys as the key of a dictionary with a list as value.

This is my code:

```
groupResult = {}
for file in filesList:
    day = file.split('.')[0]
    prod = file.split('.')[1]
    oDir = file.split('.')[2]
    key = day+"-"+prod+"-"+oDir
    if key in groupResult:
        currList = groupResult[key]
        currList.append(file)
        groupResult[key] = currList
    else:
        groupResult[key] = [file]
```

and the groupResult:

```
groupResult: {'26-cloud_in-des': ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif'], '26-LST-asc': ['26.LST.asc.16.tif'], '26-LST-des': ['26.LST.des.1.tif', '26.LST.des.10.tif', '26.LST.des.13.tif', '26.LST.des.4.tif', '26.LST.des.7.tif'], '26-NDVI-des': ['26.NDVI.des.12.tif', '26.NDVI.des.15.tif', '26.NDVI.des.3.tif', '26.NDVI.des.6.tif', '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']}
```

Is it the best way to handle?

Comment: I think this belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `setdefault`:

```
groupResult = {}
for file in fileList:
    groupResult.setdefault(file.rsplit('.', 2)[0].replace('.', '-'), []).append(file)
```

Or use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
fileList = ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif', '26.LST.asc.16.tif', '26.LST.des.1.tif', '26.LST.des.10.tif', '26.LST.des.13.tif', '26.LST.des.4.tif', '26.LST.des.7.tif', '26.NDVI.des.12.tif', '26.NDVI.des.15.tif', '26.NDVI.des.3.tif', '26.NDVI.des.6.tif', '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']
groupResult = defaultdict(list)
for file in fileList:
    groupResult[file.rsplit('.', 2)[0].replace('.', '-')].append(file)
groupResult = dict(groupResult)
```

And now both cases:

```
print(groupResult)
```

Output:

```
{'26-cloud_in-des': ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif'], '26-LST-asc': ['26.LST.asc.16.tif'], '26-LST-des': ['26.LST.des.1.tif', '26.LST.des.10.tif', '26.LST.des.13.tif', '26.LST.des.4.tif', '26.LST.des.7.tif'], '26-NDVI-des': ['26.NDVI.des.12.tif', '26.NDVI.des.15.tif', '26.NDVI.des.3.tif', '26.NDVI.des.6.tif', '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']}
```

Comment: [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

fileList = ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif', '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif', '26.LST.asc.16.tif', '26.LST.des.1.tif', '26.LST.des.10.tif', '26.LST.des.13.tif', '26.LST.des.4.tif', '26.LST.des.7.tif', '26.NDVI.des.12.tif', '26.NDVI.des.15.tif', '26.NDVI.des.3.tif', '26.NDVI.des.6.tif', '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']
result = {}
for i in fileList:
    key = re.match(r"(\d+\.[\w_]+\.[a-z]+)", i).group(1)
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(i)   #or -->result.setdefault(key.replace(".", "-"), []).append(i)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'26.LST.asc': ['26.LST.asc.16.tif'],
 '26.LST.des': ['26.LST.des.1.tif',
                '26.LST.des.10.tif',
                '26.LST.des.13.tif',
                '26.LST.des.4.tif',
                '26.LST.des.7.tif'],
 '26.NDVI.des': ['26.NDVI.des.12.tif',
                 '26.NDVI.des.15.tif',
                 '26.NDVI.des.3.tif',
                 '26.NDVI.des.6.tif',
                 '26.NDVI.des.9.tif'],
 '26.cloud_in.des': ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif',
                     '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif',
                     '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif',
                     '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif',
                     '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif']}
```

Comment: @PeterWood  Yes. I have added that as a comment in the above snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can try `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groupResult = {}
>>> for k, g in groupby(fileList, lambda x: x.rsplit('.',2)[0]):
...     k = k.replace('.','-')
...     groupResult[k] = list(g)

{'26-cloud_in-des': ['26.cloud_in.des.11.tif',
  '26.cloud_in.des.14.tif',
  '26.cloud_in.des.2.tif',
  '26.cloud_in.des.5.tif',
  '26.cloud_in.des.8.tif'],
 '26-LST-asc': ['26.LST.asc.16.tif'],
 '26-LST-des': ['26.LST.des.1.tif',
  '26.LST.des.10.tif',
  '26.LST.des.13.tif',
  '26.LST.des.4.tif',
  '26.LST.des.7.tif'],
 '26-NDVI-des': ['26.NDVI.des.12.tif',
  '26.NDVI.des.15.tif',
  '26.NDVI.des.3.tif',
  '26.NDVI.des.6.tif',
  '26.NDVI.des.9.tif']}
```

Or,

```
>>> {k.replace('.','-'):list(g) for k,g in groupby(fileList, lambda x: x.rsplit('.',2)[0])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**`dict.setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault). This allows you to set and use a default value for a given key, if the key doesn't already exist in the dictionary.

Replace:

```
if key in groupResult:
    currList = groupResult[key]
    currList.append(file)
    groupResult[key] = currList
else:
    groupResult[key] = [file]
```

with:

```
groupResult.setdefault(key, []).append(file)
```

Or you can use [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from Python's [**`collections`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module. A `defaultdict` is like a `dict` but automatically creates a value for non-existing keys when they are requested:

```
from collections import defaultdict

groupResult = defaultdict(list)

# etc

groupResult[key].append(file)
```